Updating ICal occurrence of VEVENT with RRULE so that calendars open it correctly
I'm defining a recurring event using VEVENT and RRULE, this is my plain series VEVENT definition:
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Test//Meeting//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Berlin
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20250330T030000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3
TZNAME:CEST
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20241027T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
TZNAME:CET
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20241213T205753Z
UID:64d40b160e956f3da723159d943a9f9cae5c88600921ef1bc569d825e934a7a9
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20241212T100000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20241212T110000
DESCRIPTION:[Demo] Meeting series: sadf
ORGANIZER;CN=admin lastname:mailto:test@example.com
SUMMARY:[Demo] sadf
URL;VALUE=URI:http://localhost:3000/projects/asdf/recurring_meetings/46
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20251211T000000Z
ATTENDEE;CN=admin lastname;EMAIL=test@example.com;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTI
 ON;RSVP=TRUE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:mailto:test@example.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

I modify one of the occurrences, for example extending the event by 30 minutes. I then generate a ICS just for this occurrence update, using the same UID and matching RECURRENCE-ID.
For example:
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Test//Meeting//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Berlin
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20250330T030000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3
TZNAME:CEST
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20241027T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
TZNAME:CET
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20241213T205816Z
UID:64d40b160e956f3da723159d943a9f9cae5c88600921ef1bc569d825e934a7a9
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20241220T100000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20241220T113000
DESCRIPTION:[Demo] Meeting series: sadf
ORGANIZER;CN=admin lastname:mailto:test@example.com
SEQUENCE:2
SUMMARY:[Demo] sadf
RECURRENCE-ID;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20241219T100000
ATTENDEE;CN=admin lastname;EMAIL=test@example.com;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTI
 ON;RSVP=TRUE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:mailto:test@example.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

When I open/import first the series ICS file, then the occurrence update ICS file, my calendar (Apple calendar) will "open", or rather focus on the first start event of the series. I would expect it to have focused on the changed entry, since that's the only content of the ICS file.
Am I doing something wrong? Is there a standard that would trigger the calendar to actually show the changed entry, not the start of the series?

To no avail, I also tried outputting the update.ics together with the series definition, in different orders, using a different SEQUENCE.
